# How to serve static files with Apache and dynamic content with Morbo on same server?

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite

I have Apache httpd on port 80 and Morbo httpd server on port 3000 serving perl Mojolicious code. Morbo is available only from localhost.

Now I want to set up virtual host with proxy so that static files would be served by Apache and dynamic content would be serverd by Morbo.

This is my virtual host config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName    mojo.myhost.com
    DocumentRoot  /opt/mojo/public
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond   %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond   %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule   ^(.*)  http://localhost:3000$1 [NS,P,L]
    ProxyPassReverse  /  http://mojo.myhost.com
</VirtualHost>
```

The problem is that when I try to access `http://mojo.myhost.com/` Apache subrequ is issued by Apache and request sent to Morbo is  `http://localhost:3000/error/noindex.html` and not `http://localhost:3000/`.

Here is part of mod-rewrite log:

```
[rid#2b20905c58e0/initial] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /
[rid#2b20905c58e0/initial] (3) applying pattern '^(.*)' to uri '/'
[rid#2b20905c58e0/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input='/opt/mojo/public/' pattern='!-f' => matched
[rid#2b20905c58e0/initial] (4) RewriteCond: input='/opt/mojo/public/' pattern='!-d' => not-matched
[rid#2b20905c58e0/initial] (1) pass through /
[rid#2b20905cb910/subreq] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /index.php
[rid#2b20905cb910/subreq] (1) pass through /index.php
[rid#2b20905cd920/subreq] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /index.html
[rid#2b20905cd920/subreq] (1) pass through /index.html
[rid#2b20905cb910/subreq] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /index.html.var
[rid#2b20905cb910/subreq] (1) pass through /index.html.var
[rid#2b20905cd920/subreq] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /index.htm
[rid#2b20905cd920/subreq] (1) pass through /index.htm
[rid#2b20905caf40/initial/redir#1] (2) init rewrite engine with requested uri /error/noindex.html
[rid#2b20905caf40/initial/redir#1] (3) applying pattern '^(.*)' to uri '/error/noindex.html'
[rid#2b20905caf40/initial/redir#1] (4) RewriteCond: input='/opt/mojo/public/error/noindex.html' pattern='!-f' => matched
[rid#2b20905caf40/initial/redir#1] (4) RewriteCond: input='/opt/mojo/public/error/noindex.html' pattern='!-d' => matched
[rid#2b20905caf40/initial/redir#1] (2) rewrite '/error/noindex.html' -> 'http://localhost:3000/error/noindex.html'
[rid#2b20905caf40/initial/redir#1] (2) forcing proxy-throughput with http://localhost:3000/error/noindex.html
[rid#2b20905caf40/initial/redir#1] (1) go-ahead with proxy request proxy:http://localhost:3000/error/noindex.html [OK]
```

I added `NS` flag to `RewriteRule` but subreq still modifies the URL before it is passed to Morbo.  How can I get Apache to pass / instead of /error/noindex.html to Morbo?

If both `RewriteCond` are removed from virtualhost config then it works but static files are also serverd by Morbo (which I don't like so much).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's what happens, step by step:

1. The server gets a request for `/`
2. The server checks the `-f` condition, and finds that `/` is not a file, so it matches the condition.
3. The server checks the `-d` condition, and finds that `/` **is** a directory, so it doesn't match the condition.
4. Since it doesn't match the second condition, the server tries to process it as a local file/directory. A resource ending in `/` should have an index file; so it tries looking for all the index files listed.
5. Since it can't find an index file, it wants to show you `/error/noindex.html` instead.
6. We now go back to checking the rewrite conditions, and this time we match both - there's neither a file nor a directory called `/error/noindex.html`, so this time the proxy request is made

**The solution:**

Add a RewriteRule that matches only the empty `/` and have that one do the Rewrite. Example:

```
RewriteRule   ^/$  http://localhost:3000 [NS,P,L]
ProxyPassReverse  /  http://mojo.myhost.com
```

This matches a request for only `/`.